# CSS class for p tag works in Chrome and Safari but ignored by Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have code that worked for years in Firefox but doesn't anymore, yet it works fine in Chrome and Safari. An example is http://www.georgeglazer.com/prints/com/com.html . The code for the captions under the thumbnails is:

```
.caption {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #000;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

However, in Firefox, the "caption" class is ignored and the text appears as the default p tag: flush left, larger, and in Times New Roman.

I thought maybe it was clashing with the td tag that it goes inside of, but no, it doesn't matter where I put a `<p class="caption">` tag. The caption class is still ignored.

Oddly, it's working in Firefox on pages styled for XHTML 1.0 Transitional (e.g. http://www.georgeglazer.com/prints/americana/americana.html) but not for pages styled for HTML 4.0 Transitional such as the one shown. They use different stylesheets, but the code for the "caption" class is written identically.

You may find the entire stylesheet for com.html is on our site in the menus folder and is called level2.css

Please help or tell me if you think I've found a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not like this section of your css:

```
#seealso.map { color: #006699;" } /* The only maps with this and pgbottom are asia.html, latin.html and usmaps.html */
#seealso.print { color: #996666;" } /* The only prints with this and pgbottom are com.html, industry.html */
```

... there's an issue with a couple of errant `"` in your css. Chrome is ignoring them (for whatever reason) while FireFox is choosing not to load the rest of your css file (after the first one.)

Since your `.caption` class occurs AFTER the offending `"` it's not being loaded in FireFox. If you fix this issue, everything should work correctly.

Comment: To add to this, pasting the level2.css content into http://csslint.net/ reported 10 errors and 93 warnings.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I just took out those quotation marks and all is well again. Thank you ever so much!